# How to add a EditText in circle shape and accept only 1 number

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design

how to make a edittext field in complete circle shape, not just rounded.
and force it to accept only 1 number.
i am looking for something like this [image]

\n\n

Comment: It is not a good design practice to have an EditText circle shape because users will first think it as a button. You may pick a design like entering serial number (any software installation pin code editBox). However you may use the answer below as well.

Comment: It was the demand of the UI to have circled Edittext which accepts one number each. i.e. to enter some kind of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your XML layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/circle_edittext"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:padding="20dp"
    />
```

And add a circle drawable for the background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>   <!-- CIRCLE COLOR -->
</shape>
```

Hope it helps.